# How to include sub-object in json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Hi I am trying to include the roles of a user when rendering json doing User.all
I am using ruby on rails and Mongoid

I only get the role_id in my response...

```
role_id":"56cb596bc226cb5c04efd1cb
```

User model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

  has_many :role
  belongs_to :store
  has_many :orders
```

Role model:

```
class Role
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user

  field :name, type: String
  field :active, type: Mongoid::Boolean
```

the response I get:

```
    {"_id":"...","api_key":"...","email":"jesus@drinkz.io","name":"... Garcia","password_digest":"...","promotion_ids":[],
"role_id":"56cb596bc226cb5c04efd1cb"}
```

How I get the response: GET /api/v1/users

```
def index
    @user = User.first
    respond_with @user
  end
```

How can I embed roles in the response ?

Comment: how are you getting your response?

Comment: I am using a get on /api/v1/users and returning User.first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add gem 'active_model_serializers' to your gemfile if you are not already using it . Then generate an user serializer using

```
rails generate serializer user
```

Then add following to app/serializers/user_serializer.rb file.

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email,:name, :password_digest, :promotion_ids, :api_key
  has_many :roles
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll get the JSON that represents User alone if you don't include the Role as well. You can do something like below

```
def index
  @user = User.first
  respond_with(@user, :include => :role)
end
```

Old school way would be,

```
def index
  @user = User.first
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @user.to_json(:include => :role) }
  end
end
```